# AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'Session'

Tags: python, session, python-requests, attributeerror

So I was trying to work with requests in python.
However when I tried to run my code I get this error:

> AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'Session'

I've looked for fixes for my problem but everything I tried didn't work. I've copied this code from a YouTube Tutorial where it seemed to work fine. I'm using Visual Studio Code to run and edit my code.

But if I run the entire file in the command prompt with: `python main.py` I get a completely different error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
        session = login('samuel', '1234')
      File "main.py", line 14, in login
        s.headers.update({'authorization': 
json.loads((s.post('testwebsite/Users/authenticatebyname', json=payload)).content)['token']})
      File "c:\users\samue\appdata\local\activestate\cache\267afc47\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "c:\users\samue\appdata\local\activestate\cache\267afc47\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "c:\users\samue\appdata\local\activestate\cache\267afc47\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

My Code:

```
import requests
import json


def login(name, password):

    s = requests.Session()

    payload = {
        'samuel': name,
        '1234': password
    }
    s.headers.update({'authorization': json.loads((s.post('testwebsite/Users/authenticatebyname', json=payload)).content)['token']})
    print((s.post('testwebsite/Users/authenticatebyname', json=payload)).content)
    return s



session = login('samuel', '1234')
```

Comment: Break your code down into discrete steps. You gain very little (if anything) by writing one-liners that are difficult to debug. Then you'll see where you problem really lies

Comment: What is the python version here?